# Two ways of starting pytest

Tags: python, module, pytest

I've got a project. The tests pass, if I start them like this:

```
(.venv) ~/spaces/python/dsbotbackend/src (main ✔) ᐅ python -m pytest
```

If I try just `$ pytest`, it won't run:

```
(.venv) ~/spaces/python/dsbotbackend/src (main ✔) ᐅ pytest
ImportError while loading conftest '/home/alexey/spaces/python/dsbotbackend/src/tests/conftest.py'.
tests/conftest.py:3: in <module>
from server.dbase import setup
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'server'
```

Module server is there, complete with `__init__.py`:

```
(.venv) ~/spaces/python/dsbotbackend/src (main ✔) ᐅ ls
dbase  docs  processors  __pycache__  scenarios  server  state_machine  test.db  tests
```

Why the difference and what is happening under the hood?

Comment: `python -m pytest` adds the current path to the Python path. As the modules are imported relative to this path, this is needed to find them.

Comment: This is also mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/usage.html#calling-pytest-through-python-m-pytest).